# A trouble with separator i am getting when i am trying to type one in css

Tags: css

Greetings everyone i have a problem with my separator:

```
#menu li:not(:first-child):before {
   content: " | ";
}
```

this code works but first li item does not get separated like the others. Here's the result I get :

```
test1 test2 | test3 | test4
```

Cloud someone tell me how to solve this problem?

Comment: You are selecting everything except the first element, so simply using `#menu li` will solve just that.

Comment: what result are you expecting..?

Comment: I expecting this: test1|test2|test3|test4 with Levano code i get this test1|test2|test3|test4|

Comment: your css giving the exact result you want ....  https://fiddle.jshell.net/bhuwanb9/jL0er7x9/

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

`css` amended:

> But please see there is no difference so your **css** has to work

```css
#menu li:after {
content: " | "; }

#menu li:last-child:after {
content: ""; }

#menu li {display: inline-block;}
```

```html
<ul id="menu">
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
</ul>
```

**But** like the stackoverflow community is mentioning:

This should work:

```css
  #menu li:not(:first-child):before {
       content: " | "; 
       }
       
 #menu li {display: inline-block;}
```

```html
<ul id="menu">
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What if OP adds another list-item?

Comment: ill amend @fcalderan

Comment: Why not just : `#menu li:not(:last-child):after {
content: " | "; }`
 ?

Comment: @Bhuwan i totally agree with you, but there is always more than one way to do something. Maybe not the best approach i gave but it works, if his is not.

Comment: @Ylama. The thing is that his css must works. We have to find why it is not working. Maybe today your solution will works, but maybe one day the thing that we didn't search that make his css broken, will make another thing broken.

Comment: @AlexVand i amended my answer i agree.

Comment: @Loo can you please try the second sulotion if thats not working please let me know, it should we need to find out why its not working on your side, do you have more `css` related to this menu and could you maybe add the css to the question?

Answer (score 0):

The first li is does not have the separator because of your selector which specifies that the style should *not* apply to the first `<li>`. If you want all of the `<li>` to have a separator, you should *add* this declaration to your css:

```
#menu li:first-child:after {
    content: " | ";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but with your code i get this: test1|test2 test3 test4

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is what you want, it works fine for :

(if it is not working, inspect your page to find if some css rules doesn't hide the before of the second li)

```css
#menu {
  list-style: none;
}

#menu li {
  display: inline-block;
}

#menu li:not(:first-child):before {
  content: " | "; 
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu">
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
</ul>
```